# how can i replace the try catch to not get the error exception when i am not sending the file?

Tags: java, ajax, java-ee-6

I am sending variables from ajax to java! in my ajax method I am sending 2 variables: `idtabPrest` and `idPolice`!
I am getting an error exception because I am not passing the File ! how can I make this function work and read the variables even if i am not sending the File.
I commented the Try/catch of the file to pass the variables! but in some ajax methods I am using the file.

```java
public String upload_via_ajax() {
    
    try {

        String property = "java.io.tmpdir";
        String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);
        String html = "inside upload via ajax";
//          try { 
//              File destFile = new File(tempDir, myFileFileName.substring(0,
//                      myFileFileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".csv");
//              FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);
//
//              getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("filePath",
//                      destFile.getPath());
            //POUR REFERENCE DECLARATION
            
            if(annee != null) {
                TableReferentielDto tableReferentielDto = new TableReferentielDto();
                tableReferentielDto.setId(Long.parseLong(annee));
                TableReferentielDto anneeLabel =(TableReferentielDto) tableReferentielGetByIdCmd
                .execute(tableReferentielDto);
                
                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("annee",
                        anneeLabel.getLibelle());
            }
            //POUR DATE DEBUT DECLARATION
            if(moisDebutDeclaration != null){

                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("moisDebutDeclaration",
                        moisDebutDeclaration);
            }
            //POUR DATE FIN DECLARATION
            if(moisFinDeclaration != null){
                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("moisFinDeclaration",
                        moisFinDeclaration);
            }
            //ID POLICE
            if(idPolice != null){
                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("idPolice",
                        idPolice);
            }
            if(idTabPrest != null) {
                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("idTabPrest",
                        idTabPrest);
            }
            if(idTabTarif != null){
                getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("idTabTarif",
                        idTabTarif);
            }
            
            html = "file uploaded";
        

//          } catch (IOException e) {
//
//              html = "error in uploading file";
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have a catch block like `} catch (Exception e) {  return SUCCESS; }` as you will never know which exceptions are happening.

Comment: You need to explain what you want your code to do, and what it's doing now. We don't know what you mean by "work".